# Convert month number to month name

Tags: php, date

I want to convert month number to the month name. I have tried the below code:

**A.**

```
$month = 01;
$monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month);
```

**B.**

```
$month = 01;
$monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 10));
```

**C.**

```
$month = 01;
$monthName = date("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1, 2015));
```

Here is my questions:
(1) Are they perform same output? Which one should I choose?

(2) I don't understand the 10 after the $month variable. What does it means?

(3) Any other ways to convert month number to the month name except the A, B, C?

Answer (score 1):

**Do they perform the same output?**

Most days, yes. However, if the current day is 31 and `$month` is a 30-day month, `A` will return the next month. February is problematic too, naturally.

**Which one should I choose?**

- `A` is wrong
- `B` is ok (I'd use `1` instead of `10` though)
- `C` is too much

Choose `B`.

**What does the `10` after the `$month` variable mean?**

It's the day of the month of the date you're creating with `mktime()`. If you leave it out, PHP assumes you want the same as the current day of the month. That's why `A` is wrong (bug described above).

**Any other ways?**

```
function getShortMonthNameByNumber($monthNum)
    switch ($monthNum) {
        case 1:
            return "Jan";
        case 2:
            return "Feb";
        case 3:
            return "Mar";
        // etc
    }
```

However, I'd stick with `B`.

Your code uses `date("M")`, which returns the short name of the month (`Jan`, `Feb` etc). If you want full names (`January`, `February` etc), use `"F"` instead of `"M"`.

---

*NOTE:* ***NEVER*** *write numbers with leading zeroes in source code, [because this usually means octal (instead of decimal)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). In your examples,* `$month = 08` *or* `$month = 09` *would explode your script.*

Answer (score 0):

Without using `mktme` , use `date()`

```
echo date("F");// directly to get current month ie October
```

If you alerady have date and in that you want to extract month bane, use `strrtotime()` with `date()`

```
$date = "2015-09-11";
echo date("F",strtotime($date));// will echo September
```